# Replace a string using Notepad++ and regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have strings like this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/app_res/emoji/1F60A.png" /><img src="http://www.example.com/app_res/emoji/1F389.png" />
<img src="http://www.example.com/app_res/emoji/1F61E.png" /><img src="http://www.example.com/app_res/emoji/1F339.png" />
```

I want them to be like this:

```
&#x1F60A; &#x1F389;
&#x1F61E; &#x1F339;
```

In Notepad++, I tried this :

Find what: `^\s*<img src="http://www.example.com/app_res/emoji/(1F.*).png" />`

Replace with: `&#x\1;`

The result is not as expected:

```
&#x1F60A.png" /><img src="http://www.example.com/app_res/emoji/1F389;
```

How to best isolate the regular expression ?

Any help is welcome ! Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming. For seeking help with programs alone [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/regex%20notepad++) should be your prime target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the unspecific `.` together with the [greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html#greedy) star `*`. Don't do that here, as this tends to overshoot the target.

Be more specific.

The file name (in your case) does not contain dot's. Let's use "anything except a dot" (`[^.]*`) instead of "anything" (`.*`):

```
^\s*<img src="http://www.example.com/app_res/emoji/(1F[^.]*).png" />
```

Comment: All dots outside the `[class]` should be escaped.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes, theoretically. For a one-off in an HTML file, the risk of *those particular* dots matching anything other than actual dots in the OP's file is very, very close to zero.

Comment: For your score the answer is sloppy/just a quick job: the regex could have been correct right away, and using [apostrophes for plurals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Use_in_forming_some_plurals) is questionable. Putting in a tiny bit Unicode knowledge would make the regex even more robust.

Comment: I broke multiple software's necks by using a tabulator where they were always expecting a dot to happen, always due to sloppy regexes. I am not extra searching for typos - I spot them right away when reading. Being concerned about downvotes but still not considering editing the A for the better is proof enough for me you've earned it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    <img src=".*?/([A-Z0-9]+\.\w+"\s*/><img src=".*?/([A-Z0-9]+\.\w+"\s*/>
Replace: &#x$1; &#x$2;
```

Here is a working regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMTXJR/1).

Comment: That regex is just doubled - why not incorporating repetitions right away?

Comment: @AmigoJack Good catch.  I figured that perhaps in the general case they are not the same.  Anyway, we need two separate capture groups, right?

Comment: True. Most likely OP wants to convert _any_ occurrence and not only lines of pairs. Putting spaces between what have not been spaces is already a questionable manipulation in semantic terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Find:`^<.*?/(1\w+).*?/(1\w+).*`
Replace:`&#x$1; &#x$2;`